# Check linear Independence of vectors with a non-square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In a ℝ¹⁵ space, I take two vector that I would like to check if they are linear independent. They are:

```
-0.0049    0.0000
-0.0085    0.0000
 0.3555    0.0000
 0.4364    0.3921
 0.4267   -0.2660
-0.3448    0.1596
-0.3215   -0.3921
-0.3694    0.2660
-0.2737    0.1596
-0.0992   -0.2660
 0.0758   -0.3921
 0.1163   -0.1596
 0.0348    0.2660
-0.1246    0.3921
 0.1467   -0.1596
```

How do I do it? These are two vectors for the x,y and z of 5 particles.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It is enough to check that there is some 2x2 matrix extracted from these two vectors that is nonsingular. Take for example first and last coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Two vectors are linearly independent if none of them is a linear combination of the other.

Answer (score 1):

These two vectors are linearly independent. The first coordinate is $0$ for the right vector but non-zero for the left vector whereas the forth is non-zero for both.

In general, if $v_1$ is the first vector and $v_2$ is the second vector, they are linearly dependent if you can find a real number $\alpha\neq 0$ such that $$v_1=\alpha v_2$$

Comment: Why must $\alpha$ be not zero?  If $v_1$ is any vector and $v_2$ is zero, then they are parallel, i.e., there's a non-trivial linear combination  of the zero vector, namely $0v_1+1v_2=0$.

Comment: It’s not correct yet. Suppose $v_2$ is zero ...  5xsum gave the correct answer.